# Missing poi-contrib-*.jar in the new release of POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am upgrading the POI jars to newer version ( 3.10.1 ) from old versions. I see that in the build files that poi-contrib.jar is on the class path and it has the version 2.5.1-final-20040804. 
(I am not sure why it is on the classpath). Along with 3.10.1 distributions I could not find poi-contrib.jar. I am not sure if this contrib jars are discontinued ?

Any thoughts on this ?

Regards,
JE

Answer (score 2):

Starting from version 3.7, `poi-contrib.jar` is no longer distributed.
Previous poi-contrib classes has been mostly repackaged into `poi-examples.jar`.