# where is poi ooxml out of bounds error rising from?

Tags: java, apache-poi, log4j, pom.xml

Recently, I changed the poi and poi-ooxml dependencies from

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-contrib</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

to this

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-contrib</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

and now i am getting the following exception

```
13:27:42.929 [main] INFO  com..Main - Exception thrown:
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: null
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Xobj.removeElement(Xobj.java:2099) ~[xmlbeans-5.1.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Xobj.remove_element(Xobj.java:2130) ~[xmlbeans-5.1.1.jar:?]
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTRowImpl.removeC(CTRowImpl.java:146) ~[poi-ooxml-lite-5.2.3.jar:5.2.3]
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow.fixupCTCells(XSSFRow.java:612) ~[poi-ooxml-5.2.3.jar:5.2.3]
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow.onDocumentWrite(XSSFRow.java:582) ~[poi-ooxml-5.2.3.jar:5.2.3]
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.write(XSSFSheet.java:3806) ~[poi-ooxml-5.2.3.jar:5.2.3]
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.commit(XSSFSheet.java:3749) ~[poi-ooxml-5.2.3.jar:5.2.3]
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.onSave(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:467) ~[poi-ooxml-5.2.3.jar:5.2.3]
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.onSave(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:472) ~[poi-ooxml-5.2.3.jar:5.2.3]
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.write(POIXMLDocument.java:221) ~[poi-ooxml-5.2.3.jar:5.2.3]
    at com..workbook.WorkbookHandler.writeWorkbook(WorkbookHandler.java:341) ~[DailyTrends-Reports.jar:?]
    at com..workbook.ExecutiveWorkbookHandler.generate(ExecutiveWorkbookHandler.java:90) ~[DailyTrends-Reports.jar:?]
    at com..Main.main(Main.java:64) [DailyTrends-Reports.jar:?]
```

The changes i made were to get rid of the transitive dependency of log4j dependency, which i wasnt sure where it was coming from so i added the exclusion in almost all the dependencies. I also upgraded the dep. versions. I did end up getting rid of the log4j dependency but not sure what's causing the exception. any leads would be much appreciated. thanks.

edit: i found that the log4j transitive dep was coming from poi-contrib dependency but not sure if removing the other exclusions would help

Comment: Why are you using POI jars from a mixture of versions? As per https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10204 this is documented as not working and not being supported!

Comment: @Gagravarr Thanks for the reply. I was only trying to use the latest versions of all the dependencies. are you saying that all those dep. should have the same versions? the latest version for poi contrib and poi is 5.2.3 but for poi-contrib is 3.7 beta or 3.6 so I am not sure how I can have them to be the same. Although poi and poi contrib do have 3.6 versions from back in 2010 so perhaps matching that would do the trick?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25866854/missing-poi-contrib-jar-in-the-new-release-of-poi - POI Contrib is no more, almost everything went to POI Examples, and you probably weren't using any classes out of the Jar anyway!